# Unused component shelf lifetimes

Tags: monitors, hard-disk, ssd

Is there much data about how usage and storage regime impacts the the MTBF (Mean Time Between Failure) for PC components when they serve as emergency replacement parts but really go relatively unused for many years?

Industrial SSDs degrade as you exceed their write limits.  HDDs degrade as their bearings wear out.  In both cases, I'd expect simply keeping mostly unused backup components does not shorten their operational lifetimes, no?

Anything with capacitors like screens and power supplies expects those capacitors wear out first.  Again, these do not degrade so quickly when unused, right?

(I'm asking about server or desktop components, not mobile components like batteries, which everyone knows degrade on the shelf)

Answer (score 0):

I would say there´re many factors you need to consider. So I would say it´s not always easy to answer!

But I liked your question and found this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67933/how-do-unused-electronic-components-age) with good answer! I recommend checking it out! It shows a few things to consider with electronic components. :)